Angle between two bisecting lines when given their perpendiculars
I am attempting to calculate the angle B in the attached image. Essentially, I am using a radiograph to calculate the angles of each vertebra and then computing the angles between them using the method in the image. I have gone through and determined that B is alpha-1 subtracted from alpha-2. However, I am unsure as I am using MATLAB to calculate angles and their image coordinate system mirrors the Cartesian system (x is the same but y is reversed - positive y is down versus up if that makes sense).
Is my math correct? Thank you.
enter image description here

Aren't both the images same? Moreover, changing the Y axis orientation does not seem to change the calculation of your angles...

What are $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$? Why are the two different angles both labeled $\beta$?

I apologize. I erroneously uploaded the wrong image (first time using this website). The figure should be clearer. I am not sure why they labeled both B; this figure was taken from a journal article written 20 years ago. I have the angles of the vertebrae with respect to horizontal (alpha 1 and 2) but would like to use them to derive B. I hope that is clearer.

So you found $\beta=\alpha_2-\alpha_1$ right? But, I see $\alpha_1$ has nothing to do with $\alpha_2$, then how can they be interrelated? show us some of your work...

I assume you mean the $\beta$ on the right. If you are using signed angles with $\alpha_1$ negative and $\alpha_2$ as positive, then $\beta = \alpha_2 - \alpha_1$ is correct (or if $\beta$ should be negative, then you would need $\alpha_1 > 0, \alpha_2 < 0$). But if $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ are unsigned angles (both positive), then $\beta = \alpha_1 + \alpha_2$.
